# JavaDoc for Android XML (string) resources

Tags: android, xml, documentation, javadoc, android-resources

Is there a way how to add comment/description/documentation to android resource reference? The only way I know is to use standart XML comment. Which is not ideal obviously.

Something like special attribute or special javadoc pre-element

```
<resources>
    <string documentation="Some useful information what does this resource means..." name="KEY" translatable="false">value</string>
</resources>

 <resources>
    <documentation forName="KEY">Some useful information what does this resource means...</documentation>
    <string name="KEY" translatable="false">value</string>
</resources>
```

Not ideal but currently functional way:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Some useful information about what this resource means... -->
    <string name="KEY" translatable="false">value</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following format allows for a file header (using XML documentation comments), as well as as an individual comment (a documentation attribute) that goes along with each resource entry. I haven't had the compiler complain that a specific namespace (other than `xmlns:tools`) that contains `documentation` is required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--=============================================================================================

My File description here

==============================================================================================-->

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <string name="Application_Name" documentation="Name of the application. Used as Activity Name as the title, and appears in About box">FantasticApp</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, documentation attribute works. But still it is not integrated into androidstudio show-javadoc-autocomplete feature. It is good middle step.